# How to correctly use 'whereupon'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

How to use 'whereupon'?  I'm making sense of it in the following example by taking 'whereupon' to mean 'which at'.

'This Is Jinsy is one of those weird British comedies, like The League of Gentleman and The Mighty Boosh, whereupon a first viewing, it seems inaccessibly strange but, given time, you come to embrace its eccentricities.'

Can anyone tell me if there's anything wrong with this, specifically if the 'it' can be om-it-ted?

Cheers

Comment: First, time travel back to the 1670s....

Comment: Generally? In a legal document.

Comment: I can find no prepositional usage (at any time in the history of English) of 'whereupon' and believe it to be a misprint here for _where, upon_.

Answer (score 1):

[Whereupon](http://i.word.com/idictionary/whereupon) is used to mean *immediately after which*. It is most frequently used in legal documents and police descriptions of crimes.  It is usually used to describe a sequence of events.  The usage dates back to the 14th Century, and today sounds rather dated.

> The perpetrator broke the window to the main door, whereupon he unlocked the deadbolt and let himself inside.

The usage in your example is a bit awkward. You are not describing a sequence of events, but rather describing the effect of seeing a film.

I would suggest using the words *where upon* instead of whereupon. The meaning fits your usage better.